# Shapefile to polygon, then edit the polygon in order to use it as a mold

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, vector

I am working on QGIS with a shapefile:

[image]

I transform it through Raster-> Conversion-> Polygonize

[image]

Then I eliminate some parts (Sea), and those that are bigger than one single square of grid but are inside of the mainland

[image]

I would like to fill those black gaps with no grid in the vector file with a grid of the same size of all the other squares.
I'm working on this trying to use the final polygon as a model to cut other shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn on snapping to vertices in the Snapping Toolbar.

   [image]
2. Turn on editing for the orange layer.
3. Digitize a new polygon to fill in each grid square.

   - The snapping setting will cause the split tool to snap to the corners of adjacent grid squares, which will make the new polygon edges align exactly with the rest of the grid.

   [image]

Tips:

- Next time, don't delete the polygons that fill the gaps. Instead, use the `split feature` tool to split these polygons into separate grid squares. This will be faster than digitizing new polygons (it takes 2 clicks to split a polygon vs 4 clicks to create a new feature).
- "Shapefile" is a file format that can only store vector data. Your original file is *not* a shapefile. It's some type of raster. I can't tell what format based on your screenshots. That information would be in the layer properties if you want to know.